# How to debug Angular Error : You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular11

```
Error: core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:71)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:57)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:51)``
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:34)
at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:3)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:19)
```

In the stack trace, I can see all the library files so debugging that file is not possible and there are several places I have used observables so How can I check what is the exact issue?

Comment: Without any code it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`mergeMap` will attempt to subscribe to inner observables.

You probably have an inner observable that you wish to subscribe to within a `mergeMap`, but said observable is undefined (not an observable of the value `undefined`, but simply `undefined`).

Without any code this is the most I can help.